# Spark: Saving RDD in an already existing path in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am able to save the RDD output to HDFS with **saveAsTextFile** method. This method throws an exception if the file path already exists.

I have a use case where I need to save the RDDS in an already existing file path in HDFS. Is there a way to do just append the new RDD data to the data that is already existing in the same path?

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution, available since Spark 1.6, is to use `DataFrames` with `text` format and `append` mode:

```scala
val outputPath: String = ???

rdd.map(_.toString).toDF.write.mode("append").text(outputPath)
```

Comment: I tried it. But, I got this exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.text(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Comment: Which version of Spark do you use?

Comment: Oops. I am using spark version 1.5.

Comment: In 1.5 you could do similar thing with [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) and adjusting `header` and `quoteMode`